# Not Able to connect to couchbase server

Tags: couchbase

Annoying issue...

OS : Linux

I am trying to connect to couchbase server but its causingfollowing exception. Problem is that everything was working fine and this issue has starting coming from no where. I hope its nothing to do with some port configuration or related to it...

If some one have any useful information over this, Please share with me. in the mean time, I am also looking into the issue.

Exception Stack Trace :

```
2014-11-16 07:57:00.946 WARN com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseConnection:  Problem handling Couchbase IO
java.io.IOException: Invalid argument
        at sun.nio.ch.DevPollArrayWrapper.poll0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.DevPollArrayWrapper.poll(DevPollArrayWrapper.java:170)
        at sun.nio.ch.DevPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(DevPollSelectorImpl.java:68)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:69)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:80)
        at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection.handleIO(MemcachedConnection.java:398)
        at com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseConnection.run(CouchbaseConnection.java:288)
```

I tried connecting to the same couchbase server from a sample program from my local windows box, It worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Got the reason. I was using -d64 option while calling my java program. unfortunately, the couchbase sdk I am using was only supporting 32 bit.

I removed the -d64 option and it ran fine.